# Is gitlab-runner suit for production use

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

Is the GitLab CI/CD tools suit/reliable for production use?

As more details, I have more than two servers and they've gitlab-runner inside then connected as runners to my GitLab instance. In this case, I wanna make sure that is these runners are reliable and stable if using the server as some test and production server?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Is your infrastructure in a cloud provider? If so, any architecture that allows for auto-remediation should suffice to make this production-ready. Bonus points for auto-scaling.

If you're in AWS, for example, check out these documents:

- https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/runner_autoscale_aws/
- https://github.com/npalm/terraform-aws-gitlab-runner

Comment: Is your infrastructure in a cloud provider? No. I have some virtual private servers and some of them are gitlab-runner which connected to the GitLab instance. In this case, should I trust GitLab and gitlab-runner as a production use?